# $y \in \{x:\varphi(x)\} \longrightarrow \varphi(y)$ not $\longleftrightarrow \varphi(y)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In "Axiomatic Set Theory" By Patrick Suppes there is a Theorem Schema 47:
$y \in \{x:\varphi(x)\} \longrightarrow \varphi(y)$
(available on [books.google.com](https://books.google.com/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&dq=Axiomatic+set+theory+by+P.+Suppes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL8JDkldHNAhWo6YMKHVWvBJwQ6AEIJzAA#v=snippet&q=theorem%20schema%2047&f=false), page 34)

Then on page 36 (also avilable at books.google.com) Exercise #2 asks: "Why can the implication sign in Theorem 47 not be replaced by an equivalence sign $\longleftrightarrow$?"

I'm puzzled because on the same page 34 where the theorem is stated the proof makes references to Definition Schema 11:
\begin{equation*}
y=\{x\mid\phi(x)\}\iff [y \textrm{ is a set} \land \forall x(x\in y\longleftrightarrow \phi(x))]\vee [y=\emptyset \wedge  \neg \exists B\forall x(x\in B\longleftrightarrow \phi(x))]
\end{equation*}

and the derives $y \in \{x:\varphi(x)\} \longleftrightarrow \varphi(y)$ [with a $\longleftrightarrow$!]

Could somebody please clarify me on this? Thanks!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for commenting. I did read the Definition Schema 11 before posting but the answer was not apparent to me from there. (Maybe because my lack of background as I never took any took any formal courses on set theory, just that lately I got interested in studying it for myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof of Theorem 47 relies on the assumption, from the beginning, that $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ has a member at all. But it may be that there are formulas $\phi$ such that the associated abstract is the empty set, even though there are things which satisfy the formula. For example, let $\phi$ be $x=x$; if the instance $y\in \{x:x=x\}\leftrightarrow y=y$ were true, then you would be able to prove the existence of a universal set; so this is an instance where $\phi(y)$ is true, and $y\in\{x:\phi(x)\}$ is false.

On the other hand, once you know that $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ has any member at all, then the implication works both ways *for that particular $\phi$*.

Comment: thanks. I understand what you said and it makes sense. However, in regards to this part: "But it may be that there are formulas $\phi$ such that the associated abstract is the empty set, even though there are things which satisfy the formula," are you saying that the set built by formula $y=y$ is empty even though (obviously) there are "things which satisfy the formula"? (the problem being that there are too many elements satisfying the formula, a collection that's too large to be a set, that is, a "universal set")?

Comment: @AdrianChira - Yes, in Suppes' theory, and ZF, $\{x:x=x\}$ is the empty set. You can see this from Definition Schema 11,  which says in this case that either $\{x:x=x\}$ is the entire universe, *or* that it's the empty set and there is no universal set.